# Remix Solidity Compiler does not work after the update on my browser

Tags: remix

http://remix.ethereum.org `Remix Solidity Compiler` does not work, solidity compiler does not show up.  I guess there is heavy load on the web-page of remix so browser could not handle it and freezes.

It was working yesterday but it does not today. Does anyone face with the similar issue?

[image]

=> What is the recommended browser and its version to open remix?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: It's working for me. Link gets automatically forwarded to "http://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.4.13+commit.fb4cb1a.js". Drop-down menu is also working.

Comment: which browser do you use? I was using safari that s why I guess it was not working. @RichardHorrocks

Comment: Chrome (actually Chromium), with uBlock and PrivacyBadger turned on. (Don't think it's the most recent version of Chromium though...)

Comment: When I tried firefox and chrome the problem is solved on my case. I guess safari is not good to use remix, @RichardHorrocks

Comment: Interesting. I haven't tried Safari - it might be worth raising a ticket in case it's a genuine problem. Is your Safari up to date without any add-ons that might be blocking content?

Comment: Yes everything is up to date. I guess there is heavy load on the web-page of remix, I tried on different machine, it also did not opened :( @RichardHorrocks

Comment: Can it be related to a load on the web server ? I think there was a new version. Two days ago, I tried it on Chrome, it did not work. Then, immediately, I tried it on Firefox and it worked. But today, it does NOT work on Firefox also. Therefore, I am getting suspicious that maybe a lot of people are trying to use it and web server may have excessive load problem.

Comment: When I look at the browser console, I see the following message: app.js:134518 Uncaught TypeError: container.querySelectorAll(...).forEach is not a function

Answer (score -1):

Clearing site data in Chrome DevTools->Application->Clear storage solved it for a similar problem of the Solidity compiler not loading for me.

NOTE: Any earlier contract code saved in the editor files will be lost, so please take back-up of any previous source code first before clearing site data.

Now I am able to load the current 0.4.21 version and the compiler version drop-down is populated as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try different solidity versions on setting tab.
In my case, it worked after declaring version and changing versions.

I tried pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
and version 0.4.24+commit.e67f0147